# Does the image $f(H) \subseteq G'$ for $H \subseteq G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $f:G \to G'$ be a homomorphism then for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $f(H)$ is a subgroup of $G'$.

**My attempt:**
Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ hence, $ \forall a,b \in G, ab^{-1} \in H $. So let $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$. We need to prove that $cd^{-1} \in G'$. Since $f$ is a homomorphism  $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$. There is a little step left... What shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the property of group homomrphism: $f(a^n)=(f(a))^n\;\forall\;n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

In your proof, $cd^{-1}=f(a)f(b)^{-1}=f(ab^{-1})$. Since $ab^{-1}\in H\implies f(ab^{-1})=cd^{-1}\in f(H)$.

Comment: I understand that for $\mathbb{N}$.But $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @attepl : You can write $1=f(xx^{-1})=f(xx^{-1}xx^{-1})=f(xx^{-1}xx^{-1}xx^{-1})=\cdots$ which is the same as saying $1=f(xx^{-1})=f(x^2x^{-2})=f(x^3x^{-3})=\cdots$
Hence we have 
$1=f(x)f(x)^{-1}=f(x)f(x)^{-1}f(x)f(x)^{-1}=f(x)f(x)^{-1}f(x)f(x)^{-1}f(x)f(x)^{-1}=\cdots$
which is the same as saying $1=f(x)f(x)^{-1}=(f(x))^2f(x)^{-2}=f(x)^3f(x)^{-3}=\cdots$

Comment: It means if a,b are inverse then so are f(a),f(b)

Comment: @attepl : Yes group homomorphisms preserve inverses.

Answer (score 3):

You're working on the problem backwards.  You need to prove that $f(H)$ is a subgroup, so you need to work with elements in $f(H)$.

Choose $z, w \in f(H)$.  Then $\exists x, y \in H$ with $f(x)=z, f(y)=w$.  Also, $x, y \in H \Rightarrow xy \in H \Rightarrow f(xy)=f(x)f(y)=zw \in f(H)$, so $f(H)$ is closed under the group operation.

Next, $1 \in H \Rightarrow f(1)=1 \in f(H)$.

Finally

$$z \in f(H) \Rightarrow \exists x \in H \text{ with } f(x)=z \Rightarrow x^{-1} \in H \Rightarrow f(x^{-1}) \in f(H) \text{ and } xx^{-1}=1 \Rightarrow f(xx^{-1}) =1 \Rightarrow f(x)f(x^{-1})=1 \Rightarrow f(x^{-1})=(f(x))^{-1} \Rightarrow (f(x))^{-1} \in f(H).$$

Thus, $f(H)$ is closed under the group operation, it contains the group identity, and it's closed under inverses, so it's a subgroup.

Comment: Is $f(1)=1$ true? Can you give a proof...

Comment: @attepl: Let $x\in G$. Then $f(x)=f(1x)=f(1)f(x)$. What can you do next?

Comment: Thanks.........